# Using hector_quadrotor_gazebo with externally provided poses

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,
The `hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins` package appears to have the ability to subscribe to a pose (x,y,z,phi,theta,psi) and use this information to update the pose for the simulated device.

Is it as simple as just publishing a `nav_msgs::Odometry` message with the current pose?

Do I need to use something other than
[gazebo_quadrotor_simple_controller.cpp](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/blob/hydro-devel/hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_quadrotor_simple_controller.cpp)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7036/using-hector_quadrotor_gazebo-with-externally-provided-poses/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 319 on 2014-09-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/559/airuno2l/) on 2014-09-17**:
I'm afraid your question is a little confusing. Are you asking how to command the quadrotor in Gazebo? The way to command the quadrotor in Gazebo is to publish a geomety_msgs/Twist messages on the /cmd_vel topic, as is done in the [teleop package](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor_teleop).

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2014-09-18**:
Hello, the `/cmd_vel` isn't the only topic that the node subscribes to. There are others: Odometry (state_topic_) and IMU (imu_topic_). The state has pose information in it that is supposed to be read (Line 209), but it seems that pose is read from the imu topic (Line 252).

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/559/airuno2l/) on 2014-09-19**:
Which particular node are you referring to?

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2014-09-19**:
The gazebo_quadrotor_simple_controller.cpp from the link above.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/559/airuno2l/) on 2014-09-19**:
If you are wanting to visualize the motion of a real physical quadrotor, I think you'll want to use Rviz instead of Gazebo. Gazebo is designed for simulating robots, where as Rviz is designed for visualizing real or simulated robots.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2014-09-19**:
Thanks! I'll update the title of my question accordingly. Gazebo provides sensors (think augmented reality).

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-09-22**:
Is this question resolved?

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2014-09-23**:
Hi Nate, based on my reading of the GazeboQuadrotorSimpleController::StateCallback in gazebo_quadrotor_simple_controller.cpp, I think I'm right (i.e. publishing an odom message is all that's needed). But I was seeking clarification before wading into a new codebase. I should have time later on this week to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is no simple topic where you can publish a pose to reset the position and orientation of the quadrotor. You can call the `/gazebo/set_model_state` service with the name of the quadrotor model to set a new pose, as with every model in Gazebo. The GazeboQuadrotorSimpleController plugin only accepts geometry_msgs/Twist inputs and cannot control the quadrotor's position.

However, the default quadrotor model does not use the GazeboQuadrotorSimpleController plugin, but the newer controller plugin based on ros_control (implemented in packages hector_quadrotor_controller and hector_quadrotor_controller_gazebo). This package also contains a pose controller which is not loaded by default. You can enable the pose controller by adding the string controller/pose to the list of controllers to be loaded in `hector_quadrotor_controller/launch/controller.launch`:

```
<launch>
  <rosparam file="$(find hector_quadrotor_controller)/params/controller.yaml" />

  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen" args="
    controller/pose controller/twist
  "/>
</launch>
```

The pose controller subscribes to the `command/pose` topic (geometry_msgs/PoseStamped), which is probably what you want.

The state and imu subscribers in GazeboQuadrotorSimpleController (the older plugin) and QuadrotorHardwareSim (used by the new ros_control plugin) have another purpose: If the `state_topic` or `imu_topic` parameters are non-empty, the controller plugin subscribes to these topics and uses them as the measured/estimated state to calculate the control outputs instead of the ground truth data as returned by the Gazebo API. For example, hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation estimates the pose and velocity from the simulated and noisy IMU, GPS, magnetometer and barometric pressure measurements, as a real onboard controller would do. The state_topic and imu_topic parameters are meant to feed these estimates back to the controller. If you would publish the desired poses there, this would render the quadrotor uncontrollable.

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/60/johannes-meyer/) with karma: 196 on 2014-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3